# Cannot define a type shortcut using "using"

Tags: c#, typedef

I am trying to define a shortcut to a type that I use a lot in my code:

```
using IntPair = ValueTuple<int, int>;
```

I get an error:

```
The type or namespace "ValueTuple" could not be found.
```

But, I can use ValueTuple in the rest of my code with no problem.

Is this the correct way to define the type shortcut?

Comment: You need the namespace-qualified name for the right-hand-side of the `=`, IIRC.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VgfI2t

Comment: and/or the framework version is below 4.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As detailed in the [using directives specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-alias-directives):

> the namespace_or_type_name of a using_alias_directive is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using_directives.

Which means that you should fully qualify the type you're aliasing:

```cs
using IntPair = System.ValueTuple<int, int>;
```